# Embedding of the item

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, word-embeddings, embeddings

I've got a question about embedding. I've got dataset of items of which I have a name, description and image. I want to make vector representation of them using these three features. How should I do that? I made three different models (using neural network) which are using these features to classify these items (to some categories) and I have representation of these features from embedding layers, but how can I concatenate these representations into one vector which will be the best representation of each of item? These representations have to be similar if the items are similar. 
Do you have some advice to my problem?

Best regards

Comment: If you want to have clusters of similar items, you can vectorize each feature. You can have an embedding for the name and description using Word2Vec ( and even Doc2Vec ).

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal, I want to use all of my features (name, description and image), because I think that it could be better representation of each of item. In addition, it could be more efficient for me if I could use these models (neural networks) which I prepared for categorization of items.